# gfcCardStatus not working with Sierra

Tags: macos-sierra

Having updated to MacOS Sierra (10.12), gfxCardStatus is now a dependency, so I cannot switch to the integrated graphics option. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/codykrieger/gfxCardStatus/issues/240). Fortunately [steveschow](https://github.com/steveschow) has [a branch](https://github.com/steveschow/gfxCardStatus/releases) that solves this for 2011 or later Macs, and [another branch](https://github.com/steveschow/gfxCardStatus/releases/tag/v2.4.2i) that solves it for 2010 Macs.